# Retrieve Comments from tables and columns in a Mysql database

Tags: mysql, comments, mysql-workbench

i have to build an application to manage an existing MySQL database. This database was created with MySQLworkbench and some useful comments were added to its tables and columns.

I think it would be great to somehow, query that comments and show them to the user to explain "what that field is". The problem is i don't know if its possible to retrieve that comments (they are only visible from the workbench).

### EDIT:

in the MySQL existing database i have to work with there is no INFORMATION_SCHEMA table. I think is something usual to find it but in my model there is no :S

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
 SELECT column_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='table_name';
```

Comment: in the MySQL existing database i have to work with there is no INFORMATION_SCHEMA table. I think is something usual to find it but in my model there is no :S

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the output of

```
show create table `YOURTABLE`;
```

Comment: will that sentence create a table? i don't need to create any tables. All tables i need to query are already created and comented